# Bagging vs pasting in ensemble learning

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias, ensemble, bagging

This is a citation from "Hands-on machine learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras and TensorFlow" by Aurelien Geron:

*"Bootstrapping introduces a bit more diversity in the subsets that each predictor is trained on, so bagging ends up with a slightly higher bias than pasting, but this also means that predictors end up being less correlated so the ensemble’s variance is reduced."*

I can't understand why bagging, as compared to pasting, results in higher bias and lower variance. Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation of this?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say we have a set of 40 numbers from 1 to 40.
We have to pick 4 subsets of 10 numbers.

**Case 1 - Bagging** -

We will pick the first number, put it back, and then pick the next. This makes all the draw independent and consequently have very little correlation.

So, if you make a Tree on the first 10 samples and another Tree on the next, both the trees will have little correlation and high variance(among them) (*more independent splits*).

At the same time, because of selection with replacement the data points will be repeated [*~63% unique*] [[Ref]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88993/256691), which will increase the bias of individual Trees.

> *In case of bagging, the sample size is equal to the size of the dataset but we just created this scenario to compare it with Pasting.*

Same logic goes for splitting with Random Features subset *i.e. RandomForest.*

It might be possible that a Split on a particular Feature may result in the correlated next split(always). *So if we randomly pick a subset of features before each split, then this will further reduce the Correlation. But again, we will have increased Bias.*

**Case 2 - Pasting** -

Here, because of selection without replacement, the data points in each sample will be unique which will result in lesser bias of individual Trees.

Comment: Wait, I thought Bagging was when you pick one data, replace it then pick another for each subset. No? resource -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mg8QD0F1dQ&ab_channel=Udacity